# Plotting the aggregate of sets/groups in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

have grouped a set of points into a group and/or set. Is there any possibility to plot the aggregate value or average value of the points in each set on the plot as well?

on the image below three points are selected in one group. In addition to the points attached, it would be great to have a new point that represents the sum/averages of each set.

[image: Plot of datapoint]

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to answer this question without any knowledge about your workbook/data and the grouping. From my perspective, this could be a level of detail perspective. You could try to fix on the grouping and obtain the average through this approach.

```
{FIXED My_grouping: AVG(Value)}
```